# modify apache httpd.conf using ruby

Tags: ruby, apache

Hey guys I'm trying to change in httpd.conf using ruby code 1.8.5 could you help me with it please

2. Apache configuration file The Apache configuration file must be configured specifically
   for the server you have installed it on, i.e. the ServerName configuration item must be set to the IP address of the VM, not to 127.0.0.1 or any other generic address. TheServerAdmin configuration item must be set to cit470-sp2014-teamYOUR_TEAM_NUMBER@gmail.com. Create a gmail account with that name if you
   have not done so already.
3. SSL All content must also be accessible using encrypted https versions of your URLs.
4. User directories Configure the server so that individual users can create their own web
   sites by putting files in the public_html subdirectory of their home directory. These files should be available by both URLs of the form http://your_ip/~username and of the form http://your_ip/users/username. This may require that you create rewrite rules with mod_rewrite.

   ```
   ]# ./apconfigure.rb
   ./apconfigure.rb:8: warning: parenthesize argument(s) for future version
   ./apconfigure.rb:18: syntax error
   .gsub(/ServerAdmin (.+)/, "ServerAdmin cit470su2015team2@gmail.com")
    ^
   ./apconfigure.rb:19: syntax error
   .gsub(/UserDir disable/, "UserDir public_html")
    ^
   ./apconfigure.rb:20: syntax error
   .gsub(userdir_regex, replacement) + "\nServerName 10.2.7.84  \nRewriteEngine on\nRewriteRule ^/users/(.*)$ /~$1 [PT]"
    ^
   ```

this is my code

```
  #!/usr/bin/ruby
  # This script edits the Apache configuration files and enables UserDir,
  # as well as a custom RewriteRule
  # path to apache config file
  config_file = "/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf"

  file = File.read(config _file)

  # regex to uncomment the sample UserDir directives
  userdir_regex = /#<Directory \/home\/\*\/public_html>.+?<\/Directory>/m
  replacement = file.match(userdir_regex).to_s.gsub('#','')

  # make some substitutions: change ServerName and ServerAdmin, enable UserDir,
  # add rewrite rules.
  edited_file =
     file

  .gsub(/ServerAdmin (.+)/, "ServerAdmin cit470su2015team2@gmail.com")
  .gsub(/UserDir disable/, "UserDir public_html")
  .gsub(userdir_regex, replacement) + "\nServerName 10.2.7.84 \nRewriteEngine on\nRewriteRule ^/users/(.*)$ /~$1 [PT]"

  # write the changes to the file
  File.open(config_file, 'w') do |f|
  f.puts edited_file
    end
```

Comment: [This looks like homework](http://faculty.cs.nku.edu/~waldenj/classes/2011/spring/cit470/assignments/a1.html)! But anyway, you have a Ruby error, but you have failed to provide any code for us to look at.

Comment: yes it's I just did add the code

Comment: See [this article on multi-line staements](http://rubyquicktips.com/post/6103761205/spread-command-chains-across-multiple-lines) - are you using Ruby 1.9 or greater. If so, perhaps the blank line (line 17?) between `file` and `.gsub` is confusing the parser, and it decides that the statement terminates at `file`, so please delete it.

Comment: I'm using ruby 1.8.5 (2006-08-25) [i386-linux]

Comment: anyway I fixed my program by using bash code  thank you